Error message while running a Python file on Command Prompt
I am reaching out due to an error message rendered while running a file on command prompt with Python. When typing this:
"C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.12\Waterfall Plot.py"

the following error message is rendered:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.12\Waterfall Plot.py", line 3, in <module>
    fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_waterfall.py", line 2913, in __init__
    self["connector"] = _v
    ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4866, in __setitem__
    self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5277, in _set_compound_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val, skip_invalid=self._skip_invalid)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 2484, in validate_coerce
    v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\waterfall\_connector.py", line 155, in __init__
    self["line"] = _v
    ~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4866, in __setitem__
    self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5277, in _set_compound_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val, skip_invalid=self._skip_invalid)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 2484, in validate_coerce
    v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\waterfall\connector\_line.py", line 190, in __init__
    self["color"] = _v
    ~~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4874, in __setitem__
    self._set_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5218, in _set_prop
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5213, in _set_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 1383, in validate_coerce
    self.raise_invalid_val(v)
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 296, in raise_invalid_val
    raise ValueError(
ValueError:
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of waterfall.connector.line
        Received value: 'rgb(63, 63, 63))'

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
            cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
            darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
            darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
            darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
            darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
            darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
            dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
            floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
            ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
            greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
            ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
            lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
            lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
            lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
            lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
            lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
            linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
            mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
            mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
            mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
            mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
            oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
            orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
            palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
            plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
            royalblue, rebeccapurple, saddlebrown, salmon,
            sandybrown, seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver,
            skyblue, slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow,
            springgreen, steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato,
            turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke,
            yellow, yellowgreen,

This has a link with an invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of waterfall.connector.line.
Here is the code contained in the file executed:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
    name = "20", orientation = "v",
    measure = ["relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total"],
    x = ["Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other Expenses", "Profit Before Tax"],
    textposition = "outside",
    text = ["+60", "+80", "" "-40", "-20", "Total"],
    y = [60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0],
    connector = {"line":{"color":"rgb(63, 63, 63))"}},))
    

fig.update_layout(
        title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
        showlegend = True
)

    
fig.show()
    

Does anyone know how can I execute this without getting through this error message?
Greetings.

you've not shown any code just a slew of trace messages ... how are we to respond ?  , have you made any attempt at debugging/amending/testing - try some of those first.

There is this part that refers to the error: "ValueError:
Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of waterfall.connector.line
Received value: 'rgb(63, 63, 63))'".

That's wholly unusable wrt helping us help you. Have you tried debugging/amending/testing the source (as previously asked ) , until you've shown some attempt as doing basic research I don't think we can make any further progress.

The error message seems to tell you what's wrong:
Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'color' property of waterfall.connector.line
        Received value: 'rgb(63, 63, 63))'

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
            cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
            darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
            darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
            darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
            darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
            darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
            dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
            floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
            ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
            greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
            ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
            lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
            lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
            lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
            lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
            lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
            linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
            mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
            mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
            mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
            mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
            oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
            orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
            palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
            plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
            royalblue, rebeccapurple, saddlebrown, salmon,
            sandybrown, seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver,
            skyblue, slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow,
            springgreen, steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato,
            turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke,
            yellow, yellowgreen,

The error message tells you what kind of input is supported for the color option.
You provided
'rgb(63, 63, 63))'

Remove one of the closing ), and maybe the spaces after the commas.
'rgb(63,63,63)'

